# What is the best way to build a interface for bacnet system?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, bacnet

I tried to build an interface for a `bacnet` system, and I thought a web app, desktop app, and movil app, all written in Java would be a good Idea. But I don't know how build the bridge between bacnet network and my app.

Comment: When I search "bacnet Java API" the first hit I get is http://www.scadaengine.com/software5.html which seems a plausible hit. Did you even try to solve that yourself? If so, please add the libraries that you have tried and that failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a BACnet stack for Java on SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bacnet4j/

Answer (score 0):

You should use some third party library that solves the bridging for you.

Have a look at the results here: [Websearch](https://ixquick.com/do/search?q=bacnet%20Java%20API) and see if one of these help you.